# create lists of unique names in a for -loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, unique

I want to create a series of lists with unique names inside a for-loop and use the index to create the liste names. Here is what I want to do

```
x = [100,2,300,4,75]

for i in x:

  list_i=[]
```

I want to create empty lists such as

```
lst_100 = [], lst_2 =[] lst_300 = []..
```

any help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't make dynamically named variables. It makes it hard to program with them. Instead, use a dict:

```
x = [100,2,300,4,75]
dct = {}
for i in x:
    dct['lst_%s' % i] = []

print(dct)
# {'lst_300': [], 'lst_75': [], 'lst_100': [], 'lst_2': [], 'lst_4': []}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do with while keeping the order of the original x? Instead I see here, and in root's answer, that the "100, 2, 300, 4, 75" order was not preserved. I imagine this is some dict property.

Comment: @Coolio2654: Right. `dict` keys are not ordered. To preserve the order in which the keys were inserted, use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict): (change `dct = {}` --> `import collections` followed by `dct = collections.OrderedDict()`).

Answer (score 9):

Use a dictionary to hold your lists:

```
In [8]: x = [100,2,300,4,75]

In [9]: {i:[] for i in x}
Out[9]: {2: [], 4: [], 75: [], 100: [], 300: []}
```

To access each list:

```
In [10]: d = {i:[] for i in x}

In [11]: d[75]
Out[11]: []
```

And if you really want to have `lst_` in each label:

```
In [13]: {'lst_{}'.format(i):[] for i in x}
Out[13]: {'lst_100': [], 'lst_2': [], 'lst_300': [], 'lst_4': [], 'lst_75': []}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, you just go to it first :P

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND -- I think it is the most pythonic way to do it :)

Comment: Is this a *dictionary comprehension*? :-)

Comment: Hey, can I use d[75] to append some data?

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation to the other's dict-solutions is to use a defaultdict. It allows you to skip the initialisation step by invoking the chosen type's default value.

In this case the chosen type is a list, which will give you empty lists in the dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[100]
[]
```