# Creating a list within a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have created a "mastermind" style game where a user guesses the exact sequence of numbers that the computer generates.

I wanted to add a feature where the previous guesses were stored so that they could be replayed to the user before making the next guess

In my head and with the current program layout I thought It would be good if I could create a series of "pul" (previous user list).

For example, as the while loop runs and the "count" variable increases, the lists are name appropriately.

cl, computer list

ul, user list

ol, output list

pul, previous user list

when count = 0, user inputs create the ul = [1, 3, 4, 8]

pul_0 = ul

'# so pul_0 = [1, 3, 4, 8]

and when count = 1, user creates new list for ul = [2, 2, 9, 0]

pul_1 = ul

'# so pul_1 = [2, 2, 9, 0]

'# and of course pul_0 still = [1, 3, 4, 8]

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Here is a bit of code to give more detail, full program at the bottom to give more context, if needed.

```
n = int(input("how many numbers to guess? (normally 4)"))

att = int(input("how many attempts? (normally 10)"))

count = 0
while count < att:

    ul = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]

    pul(count) = ul

    count = count + 1
```

I have read a bit about using dictionaries to solve this, but didn't get them to work for me
[create lists of unique names in a for -loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819849/create-lists-of-unique-names-in-a-for-loop-in-python)

`{'pul_{}'.format(count):[] for i in ul}`

full program below

```
n = int(input("how many numbers to guess? (normally 4)"))

att = int(input("how many attempts? (normally 10)"))

cl = [randint(0, 9) for i in range(n)]

wincount = 0
count = 0

while count < att:

    print(att-count, "attempts remaining. Please enter",n, "numbers, pressing enter between each")

    ul = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]



    wincount = 0
    nearcount = 0
    for i in range (n):

        if cl[i] == ul[i]:
            wincount = wincount + 1

        for j in range (n):
            if cl[i] == ul[j]:
                nearcount += 1

    nearcount = nearcount - wincount

    if wincount == n:
        print("winner")
        count = att + 1

    if wincount != n:
        print("you have", wincount,"correct numbers in the correct positions")
        print("you have a further", nearcount,"correct numbers, but they are in the wrong positions")
        count = count + 1




if count == att:

    print("no more attempts, game over")
    print("btw the correct answer was", cl)
elif count == att + 1:
    print("nice 1")


'''



I have read a small amount about using a dictionary to try and solve this issue, but i played around with it a little and didn't get very far.

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Will be good to apply some formatting to let other not closing your question after brief view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code modified

```
n = int(input("how many numbers to guess? (normally 4)"))
att = int(input("how many attempts? (normally 10)"))
count = 0
pul = {}  # here're your previous lists, currently empty
while count < att:
    ul = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]
    pul[count] = ul  # you can use more flexible key value, as you mentioned
    count = count + 1
    # if you need to replay lists - you just use your "pul" dict
for i in range(count):
    print(f'your № {i} list was {pul.get(i)}')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While your code may answer the question, it is better if you clearly explain what it does and why it solves the OP's problem. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for further guidance.